# plm package in R does not load

Tags: r, plm

this is my first time posting a question here, so please forgive me if it is not clear enough or if I haven't supplied enough information.

I'm trying to load in the plm library (for panel regression) in R after having installed it and get the following error:

```
install.packages("plm")
library(plm)
```

R then gives me this error:

```
> library(plm)
error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plm’:
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

My R version is 3.6.3
Any help would be much appreciated!
Please let me know if you need more info to help me solve the issue.

Comment: To my limited knowledge, it's always to point out exactly what went wrong for such an error message. Maybe try installing the dependencies, that is `install.packages("plm", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: Hi! I already tried installing with dependencies but I still get the same error: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: Maybe then try installing the package manually from github. For example, use `devtools::install_github("cran/plm")`. If there is any error, then install `devtools` package first and then try `install_github("cran/plm")`.

Comment: Works fine on my side with R 3.6.3 64 bit on Windows. Also the CRAN checks of that package for R 3.6.3 (currently termed oldrel) work just fine: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-oldrel-windows-ix86+x86_64/plm-00check.html . Thus, I suspect it something specific to your machine. Maybe try to delete the package library and make a fresh install for all packages.